# Deployment on Appengine getting Error Response: [13] Unexpected Error

Tags: java, spring-boot, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, deployment

I am trying to deploy simple spring-boot maven application in  App Engine.
This is my pom.xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0">
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"> xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0> https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.3</version>
        <relativePath />
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.Ankit</groupId>
    <artifactId>Kubernetes</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1- SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Kubernetes</name>
    <description>Demo project for> Kubernetes</description>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-starter-sql-mysql</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.8.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-plugin-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.27</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
                <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <deploy.version>1</deploy.version>
                    <deploy.projectId>xenon-sentry-338907</deploy.projectId>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <finalName>kubernetes</finalName>
    </build>
</project>
```

application.properties :

```
spring.jpa.show-sql:true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create #server.port = 8080
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect 
instance connection name from the previous step
spring.cloud.gcp.sql.instance-connection-name=
xenon-sentry-338907:us-central1:testsql
spring.cloud.gcp.sql.database-name=mydb2
spring.datasource.username=root 
        spring.datasource.password=root
spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size=10
spring.datasource.continue-on-error=true
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always
spring.jpa.hibernate.use-new-id-generator-mappings=false
spring.cloud.gcp.project-id= xenon-sentry-338907 and
```

App.yaml file :

```
runtime: java 
env: flex 
runtime_config: jdk: openjdk8
 env_variables: SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE: "gcp,mysql" 
handlers: 
    - url:/.* 
    script: this field is required, but ignored 
manual_scaling:
    instances: 2
```

This is the error: Updating service [default] (this may
take several minutes)failed. ERROR: Error Response: [13] An internal
error occurred.

I can see the image in container registry but not any
instance please help me .
I am using java 8 and flex env and using gcloud app deploy command.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sz9ky.png)

I have attached Logfiles screenshot for your reference.

Comment: Take a moment to read through the [editing help](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the help center. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than on other sites. The better your post looks, the easier it is for others to read and understand it.

Comment: Are you deploying to app engine standard or app engine flex? Are you using Java 8 or Java 11? What command are you using to deploy? The error you posted gives no detail. Please look at your app engine logs and relay any errors: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/building-app/viewing-service-logs

Comment: I am deploying on app engine flex and using JAVA 8 . and using gcloud app deploy command

Comment: Please help me , I am stuck here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend using the Maven Plugin to deploy:

```
<plugin>
   <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
   <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>2.4.0</version>
</plugin>
```

And deploy with command:
`mvn package appengine:deploy -Dapp.deploy.projectId=PROJECT_ID`

[Find full instructions here.](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/using-maven#adding_the_maven_plugin_to_an_existing_project_optional)

If you are deploying a pre-built container, you can use the command:
`gcloud app deploy src/main/appengine/app.yaml --image-url gcr.io/YOUR_PROJECT_ID/YOUR_CONTAINER_IMAGE`

[See troubleshooing guide here.](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/testing-and-deploying-your-app#troubleshooting)